# What is the best way to create a dictionary using unique column values, and the corresponding range?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary with keys being the alphabetized, unique values of a column, and the values being the value of range.

So for example, If i have a column called "States" that we expect to have 50 unique values, there would be 50 keys, each containing a state. I would want the corresponding key to be 1 for the first key, and 50 for the last key.

The dictionary would look like this: {'AL':1, 'AK':2, .... 'WV':49, 'WY':50}

Ive tried something as follows -

```
mapper = {df.Statee.unique().tolist()[i]:i for i in range(1, len(df.State.unique().tolist()+1))}
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this strikes me as most readable:

```py
uniqs = df.State.unique()
mapper = {k:v+1 for v, k in enumerate(uniqs)}
```

Comment: how'd i not think of using enumerate!? this worked perfect. thank you.

Comment: Pandas is like that.  It bamboozles you into thinking you need .very_special().loc[undreadable,:cl::ever]_method() ;) feel free to accept :)